# Sums and harmonic series

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-numbers

I found the solution of series on Wolfram Alpha 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(2k%2B1)%2F(2k%2B2)+from+1+to+n

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(H_{n+\frac{1}{2}} - H_{n+1} -1 + \text{ln}(4)\right)$

Can someone tell how to prove this in the form of Harmonic numbers?

Comment: @ Tayyab Ilyas: It came as a surprise to me to see your complicated formula (with half number index and $\log$) for the sum instead of the simple $s=-H_n+H_{2 n+1}-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+1\right)$ which has an elementary derivation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the specific question but a long comment which gives a derivation of a much simpler formula for the sum in question.

Let

$$s = \sum _{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2 k+1}-\frac{1}{2 k+2}\right)$$

Adding and subtracting a sum of even terms we get for $s$

$$\begin{array}
&=& \sum _{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2 k}+\frac{1}{2 k+1}\right)-\sum _{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2 k}+\frac{1}{2 k+2}\right)\\
=& (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+ ... + \frac{1}{2n+1})-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}) -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+ \frac{1}{n+1})\\
=&(H_{2n+1}-1) -\frac{1}{2}H_n -\frac{1}{2}(H_{n+1}-1)\\
=&H_{2n+1} -\frac{1}{2}(H_n +H_{n+1})-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
$$

Those who wish can simplifiy this further using the relation $H_{n+1}=H_n + \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We will make use of the following [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Hyperharmonic_numbers) for the harmonic numbers
$$H_x = \int^1_0 \frac{1 - t^x}{1 - t} \, dt. \tag1$$

Let
$$S = \sum^n_{k = 1} \frac{1}{(2k + 1)(2k + 2)} = \sum^n_{k = 1} \left (\frac{1}{2k + 1} - \frac{1}{2k + 2} \right ).$$
Noting that
$$\int^1_0 x^{2k} \, dx = \frac{1}{2k + 1} \quad \text{and} \quad \int^1_0 x^{2k + 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2k + 2},$$
our sum can be rewritten as
$$S = \sum^n_{k = 1} \int^1_0 (x^{2k} - x^{2k + 1}) \, dx = \int^1_0 (1 - x) \sum^n_{k = 1} x^{2k} \, dx.$$
As the finite sum appearing here is geometric, it can be summed. As
$$\sum^n_{k = 1} x^{2k} = \frac{x^2 (1 - x^{2n})}{1 - x^2},$$
one has
$$S = \int^1_0 \frac{x^2 ( 1 - x^{2n})}{1 + x} \, dx = \int^1_0 \left [\frac{x^2}{1 + x} - \frac{x^{2n + 2}}{1 + x} \right ] \, dx = I_1 - I_2.$$

The first integral is trivial. Here
$$I_1 = \int^1_0 \frac{x^2}{1 + x} \, dx = \int^1_0 \left (x - 1 + \frac{1}{1 + x} \right ) \, dx = \left [\frac{x^2}{2} - x + \ln (1 + x) \right ]^1_0 = -\frac{1}{2} + \ln (2).$$

For the second integral
\begin{align*}
I_2 &= \int^1_0 \frac{x^{2n + 2}}{1 + x} \cdot \frac{1 - x}{1 - x} \, dx = \int^1_0 \frac{(1 - x) x^{2n + 2}}{1 - x^2} \, dx.
\end{align*}
Letting $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ gives
\begin{align*}
S &= \frac{1}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{x^{n + 1/2} - x^{n + 1}}{1 - x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{(1 - x^{n + 1}) - (1 - x^{n + 1/2})}{1 - x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{1 - x^{n + 1}}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{1 - x^{n + 1/2}}{1 - x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left (H_{n + 1} - H_{n + 1/2} \right ),
\end{align*}
where we in the last line we have made use of (1).

Thus
$$\sum^n_{k = 1} \frac{1}{(2k + 1)(2k + 2)} = \ln (2) - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \left (H_{n + 1/2} - H_{n + 1} \right ),$$
as required.

Comment: Dear many thanks for this derivation. Is this derivation valid when $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, the expression I give is valid for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: for $\alpha=1$, I have the following result
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2} \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-H_{\frac{n}{2}+1} + H_\frac{n+1}{2} -1 + \text{ln}(4)\right)$

Do you think, this is correct for even $n's$  ${i.e.,}$ $n=2,4,6, \cdots$?

Answer (score 0):

If you use polygamma functions
$$S_1=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$S_2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+2}=\frac{1}2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{2} (\psi ^{(0)}(n+2)+\gamma -1)$$ making 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2}\right) = S_1-S_2$$ $$S_1-S_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2} (\psi ^{(0)}(n+2)+\gamma -1)$$

If you look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) $$H_n=\gamma +\psi ^{(0)}(n+1)$$ making
$$S_1-S_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}-H_{n+1}-H_{\frac{1}{2}}+1\right)$$
and $1-H_{\frac{1}{2}}=\log (4)-1$ and then the result.